# Добавление HTML в HTML

Tags: html

Есть HTML файл в который динамически добавляется html (разметка сайта) код конструкцией
[#inc main.html#], важно вставлять его именно так, иначе вставленный код не будет отрабатывать корректно.
Проблема заключается в том, что основной файл используется в разных местах  и если жестко вписать такую конструкцию то полученный код появляется в других местах.
Возможно ли сделать проверку условия, например если имя страницы такое 1.htm код отрабатывает, а если 2.html то нет.
Просто слабо понимаю что за конструкция.
По факту это конструкция от сцены умного дома, а сцен несколько.
Я так понимаю этот код выполняется на сервере.
Шаблонизатор jTemplates.
Спасибо!

Comment: В самом HTML нет такой конструкции. Скорее всего используется (использовался) какой-то шаблонизатор. Укажите в вопросе, что за шаблонизатор используется.

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно это он jTemplates (операторы вида [#if..#], [#inc ...#] или это XSLT, Smarty, FastTemplate.